# display single row from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array for exercise programs, storing exercises by day and week. I need to display a single day's exercises. Currently, I can only display all data using nested where loops. Here is the structure (simplified):

```
array(
    array( Week 1,
        array( Day 1,
            array( exercise 1, exercise 2, exercise 3))
        array( Day 2,
            array( exercise 1, exercise 2, exercise 3))
    array( Week 2,
        array( Day 1,
            array( exercise 1, exercise 2, exercise 3))
        array( Day 2,
            array( exercise 1, exercise 2, exercise 3))
)
```

How do I display only the contents of Week 2, Day 1?

Comment: Please use `print_r($your_array)` and put output here. Also refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using a While loop and an If statement with a counter. This solution uses functions from Advanced Custom Fields;

```
$i = 0;
while have_rows('week_rows') ): the_row();
  $i++;

  if( $i == $week_number ) {  // stops on the 5th row of 'week_rows' array
    break;
  }

endwhile; // I had to move the endwhile up before my display statements

// add display statements here to display array contents from 5th array row

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of week 2, day 1 just use: `$var[1][0]`